# UINavigationController pop several layers

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, root

I am building an app with the storyboard feature in ios5. I am using a navigation controller. In one situation, I drill down through several viewcontrollers: when I click the back button I would like to go directly to the root viewcontroller, instead of back through the chain of viewcontrollers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, in the view controller that you want to pop back, add this:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}
```